Login keyring not being unlocked after login into the user from a password lock-screen
Context:

Some time ago I modified the set timeout for user locking for wrong password input via modifing /etc/pam.d/common-auth.
I have lock-screen set up at start-up, meaning it ask me for my password every time I boot. DO NOT HAVE AUTO-LOGIN
I haven't changed the password
The keyring and the login password is the same one

All that said, every time I want to use a stored password, for signing or whatever, it shows me the "unlock login keyring" prompt.
Thanks in advance

This does not happen if the default keyring is unlocked at login with the current login password, so check that. It has basically nothing to do with the login screen.

Looking in seashore, I only have 1 keyring and the password for the keyring is the same as the one for the user, idk much else, thanks for the response

Make sure it gets unlocked at login.

Yeah, it's not being unlocked, that is exactly my problem. How should I set it up? I tried this but did not work, and those lines are already included in the common-auth and common-session anyways

Is the keyring named Login?

Yeah it is. May cause trouble that I changed the user lang to spanish? (Installation is in english)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/2060575

problem resolved after removing the added lines to common auth
auth    required                    pam_faillock.so preauth audit deny=3 unlock_time=900 # <---- removed
auth [success=2 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_sss.so use_first_pass

# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    [default=die]       pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=3 unlock_time=900 # <---- removed
auth    sufficient          pam_faillock.so authsucc audit deny=3 unlock_time=900 # <---- removed

but now idk how to set a longer unlock_time without breaking the login keyring
